# Convert Indexed Array to Associate Array with Indexed Exploded Values

Tags: php, arrays

Having issues converting an array like this into an associative array

> $array =

```
Array
(
    [0] => 154654654455|WS01
    [1] => 456541232132|WS02
)
```

Into an associative array.

I can do a foreach loop and explode the values

```
$values2 = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $values2[] = explode("|",$value);
}
```

But then I get something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 154654654455
            [1] => WS01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 456541232132
            [1] => WS02
        )
)
```

What's the best way to convert something like this into an associative array like such

```
Array
(
    [154654654455] => WS01
    [456541232132] => WS02
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant way, but modifying your approach it would be:

```
$values2 = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $t = explode("|",$value);
    $values2[$t[0]] = $t[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.. I was close but the new brackets caused some confusions.  Will accept this answer when I can as he answered first!

Comment: thats fair, I hate when people accept answers that were not first... when I was writing mine, there were no answers yet

Comment: I guess we pretty much answered at the same time - I still upvoted your answer to be fair

Comment: I actually think that @FlashThunder was first (if you sort the answers on "oldest", that answer comes first). But yes, in this case, the answers were about 1-2 seconds apart so basically at the same time :-) I also up voted the other correct answers :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$values2 = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $expl = explode("|",$value);
    $values2[$expl[0]] = $expl[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change your foreach loop to this

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $temp = explode("|",$value);
        $values2[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to set the the first item of the explode as key and the second as value:

```
$array = [
    '154654654455|WS01',
    '456541232132|WS02',
];

$values2 = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $data = explode('|', $value);
    $values2[$data[0]] = $data[1];
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/cEJE5

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but for completeness; after your loop you can extract the `1` column as values and index on the `0` column:

```
$values2 = array_column($values2, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to put the `exact same` answer here as everyone else,but I will omit the unused `$key` variable...

```
$val2 = array();

foreach ($array as $v) {
    $tmp = explode("|",$v);
    $val2[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
```